# ActivityResultLauncher unresolved reference

Tags: java, android, kotlin

As you know pick image from gallery or etc. change using of it. You have to use **ActivityResultLauncher**. Hovewer, sometimes it could not show. because of that:

```
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to update your **build gradle**

```
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
```

to

```
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.1'
```

Now problem will fix